# google maps api only shows maps on screen resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a problem with google maps api where the map shows blank space and only works when i resize screen size.

i read all about the `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` and tried everything on the web,
but somehow i can't use it properly on my code to get it working would appreciate fast help.
here is my jquery script:

```js
    var markers3 = [];
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var yourStartLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.71083783530009, 51.455841064453125);
        $('#map_canvas3').gmap({'center': yourStartLatLng, zoom: 10})
            .bind('init', function (event, map) {
                $(map).click(function (event) {

                    var objectOfCoordinatesInArray = [];
                    var a = {};

                    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
                    var lng = event.latLng.lng();

                    objectOfCoordinatesInArray.push(lat.toString())
                    objectOfCoordinatesInArray.push(lng.toString())

                    a["coordinates"] = objectOfCoordinatesInArray;
                    a["type"] = "Point";
                    eJSON = JSON.stringify({
                            Point: a
                        }
                    );
                    console.log(eJSON)
                    center: yourStartLatLng;
                });


                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
                    clearMarkers()
                    placeMarker(event.latLng);
                });

                function clearMarkers() {
                    setMapOnAll(null);
                    markers3 = [];
                }

                function setMapOnAll(map) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < markers3.length; i++) {
                        markers3[i].setMap(map);
                    }
                }




                function placeMarker(location) {

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: location,
                        map: map
                    });

                    markers3.push(marker);

                }
            });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

P.S dont mind the markers part its for JSON.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (you haven't provided the HTML or CSS required to display anything, or or the javascript libraries required).

Answer (score 0):

The sample you provided is incomplete and we cannot replicate your issue with just that.

But your problem is probably coming from how you initialize the map, which is from `document.ready`. I recommend you always have a `callback` reference when you include the Maps Javascript API script and have it be called asynchronously like so:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

That way once the Maps Javascript loads, it will go do `initMap()` right after, and not have issues with it appearing/disappearing.

You don't even need jquery to do what your sample code does too. Just define your `google.maps.Map` in a `map` variable and add listeners to it with `map.addListener('click', function(e){})` etc. No need to use jQuery bind.

Take a look at the snippet provided below and follow this method in loading your map.

Hope it helps. And also hope that you can use this as a reference when you provide minimal, complete, and verifiable examples next time.

```js
var markers3 = [];
var map;
var yourStartLatLng = {
  lat: 35.71083783530009,
  lng: 51.455841064453125
};

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: yourStartLatLng,
    zoom: 10
  });

  map.addListener('click', function(event) {
    var objectOfCoordinatesInArray = [];
    var a = {};

    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
    var lng = event.latLng.lng();

    objectOfCoordinatesInArray.push(lat.toString())
    objectOfCoordinatesInArray.push(lng.toString())

    a["coordinates"] = objectOfCoordinatesInArray;
    a["type"] = "Point";
    eJSON = JSON.stringify({
      Point: a
    });
    console.log(eJSON);
    //center: yourStartLatLng;
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    clearMarkers()
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });

}

function clearMarkers() {
  setMapOnAll(null);
  markers3 = [];
}

function setMapOnAll(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers3.length; i++) {
    markers3[i].setMap(map);
  }
}

function placeMarker(location) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });

  markers3.push(marker);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCD0rWgXRVBa7PgaTWXVp_gU51pgHGviYY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<style>
  /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
  
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
  
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
```